# Upgrading from Selenium 3 to Selenium 4 generates Compound class names not permitted

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am upgrading the company automation framework from `3.x` to `4.8.1`
FYI: The automation framework has been running for couple years and it is stable and functional

I see the following

Any idea what is the reason for the error?

```
Compound class names not permitted
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#invalid_selector_exception
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '14'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
null
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Compound class names not permitted
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#invalid_selector_exception
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '14'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByClassName.\<init\>(By.java:310)
at org.openqa.selenium.By.className(By.java:100)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.AbstractFindByBuilder.buildByFromShortFindBy(AbstractFindByBuilder.java:43)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy$FindByBuilder.buildIt(FindBy.java:85)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.Annotations.buildBy(Annotations.java:79)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.\<init\>(DefaultElementLocator.java:58)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.\<init\>(DefaultElementLocator.java:46)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocatorFactory.createLocator(DefaultElementLocatorFactory.java:33)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultFieldDecorator.decorate(DefaultFieldDecorator.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:111)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:103)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:90)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:78)
at pages.MCDashboardPage.\<init\>(MCDashboardPage.java:439)
at tests.MCOffenderIntakeTests.testAddNewOffender(MCOffenderIntakeTests.java:444)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:599)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:822)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$`your text`000(SuiteRunner.java:28)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:425)
at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil.lambda$execute$0(ThreadUtil.java:66)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Test Case: testAddNewOffender COMPLETE
```

Comment: If the class name for the selector you are using has space you'll get the above error  , Replace the spaces with . 
for e.g. "class class-a" with ".class.class-a